# report builder - conditional grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a Sql query :

```
SELECT
  [Order].Quantity
 ,[Order].Refund
 ,[Order].Price
 ,[Order].Archive AS [Order Archive]
 ,[Order].Handled
 ,[Order].[Date] AS [Order Date]
 ,[Order].OrderNum
 ,[Order].SecondaryID
 ,SUM((Quantity - (ISNULL(Refund, 0))) * Price) As Total
 ,Product.CatalogNum
 ,Product.ProductName
 ,Customer.CustomerName
 FROM
 [Order]
 INNER JOIN Customer
 ON Customer.CustomerID = [Order].CustomerID
 INNER JOIN Product
 ON Product.ProductID = [Order].ProductID
 WHERE [Order].OrderNum In (@order) 
 Group By [Order].Quantity,
 [Order].Refund
,[Order].Price
,[Order].Archive
,[Order].Handled
,[Order].[Date]
,[Order].OrderNum,Product.CatalogNum
,Product.ProductName
,Product.ProductPrice
,Customer.CustomerName,Customer.CustomerID
,[Order].SecondaryID Order by Customer.CustomerID,[Order].Quantity
```

I use it to build a report in Report Builder 3.0.
For the SQL, I get the results I want. But when using the report tool, when the price is different for the same product (special sales etc.) I have a problem. I dont get the sum quantity for the products.
If all rows for the same product have the same price, I do a SUM - everything is great.
If the price is different, I need to get a SUM for each price group for the same product.

any idea how to proceed?

I

Comment: Do you want the same of all prices even if they are different?

Comment: I have grouping on Product.CatalogNum
 ,Product.ProductName. they will not be different.

Answer (score 2):

In your GROUP BY clause, remove the line

```
,Product.ProductPrice
```

This is causing it to group differently on different prices. Removing it will make it group at the product name regardless of price.